# Why was my "not an answer" flag rejected?

Tags: support, flags

I recently flagged [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/362525/124566) as not an answer to the question. The flag was declined with the message stating there was no evidence that supported it.

The question is specially for [pokemon-x-y](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-x-y) whereas the answer is based on new features released in [pokemon-sword-shield](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-sword-shield).

While is the answer is valid for the newer games (which has since been expanded on and migrated to [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/362566/can-a-level-100-pok%C3%A9mon-evolve-in-any-pok%C3%A9mon-series-game) post), it is not a valid answer for the question it was posted on. With that said, why was the flag rejected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Not an answer" is for posts that aren't even *attempting* to answer the question.

This is an answer. It's just a wrong one. A downvote is more appropriate.

Comment: I figured that was the case. I've used this flag before for similar cases (can't remember any off the top of my head) and the flag is approved, so it just seemed weird in this case (to me that is). Thanks for your input :)

Comment: @Wondercricket It's hard to comment without a specific example. Sometimes an a NAA is just so hard to understand and parse that it also falls under "Very Low Quality", and so the flag was approved. Other times, the answerer will leave a comment indicating they want the answer deleted, now that someone pointed out the answer was wrong. And of course, sometimes mods just make a mistakes. Always feel free to reflag any post you think was handled incorrectly though, and the mod team is more than happy to give it a second look.